# Thousands of URL's to json markup

Tags: javascript, python

I made a Python program that can crawl a site and it takes all the URL's of the website, it downloads the data as pure links. Like:

```
google.com
quora.com/example
```

How can you place these links in JSON markup using any tool, Javascript or Python like this?

```
 {
        'url':'google.com',

    },
 {
        'url':'quora.com/example',

    },
```

Comment: My understanding is that you can't have duplicate keys in the JSON.

Comment: Put the links into a list, and call `json.dump()` on the list.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Could you provide a valid JSON format.
See https://jsonlint.com/ to test if your JSON is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a python dictionary as follows. Appending as needed to the list (which is the associated value for the key "urls":

```
 my_dict = {
    "urls": ["google.com", "quora.com/example"]
 }
```

Then you could use the [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function to get you a valid json string:

```
import json
json_string = json.dumps(my_dict)
```

Which should look like this:

```
print(json_string)

{"urls": ["google.com", "quora.com/example"]}
```